# Discord bot response python

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

So I'm having trouble with my codes, there are three files: main.py, responses.py, bot.py

So the bot is simple, It gets a 'hello' command and responds, but for some reason the input has problems I have trouble understanding the problem.

Here are the codes:

main.py:

```py
import bot

if __name__ == "__main__":
    bot.run_discord_bot()
```

bot.py:

```py
from responses import handle_response
import discord
from responses import handle_response

async def send_message(message, user_message, is_private):
    try:
        response = handle_response(user_message)
        await (message.author.send(response) if is_private else message.channel.send(response))
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

def run_discord_bot():
    TOKEN = 'MY_TOKEN'
    intents = discord.Intents.default()
    client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

    @client.event
    async def on_message(message):
        if message.author == client.user:
            return

        username = str(message.author)
        user_message = str(message.content)
        channel = str(message.channel)

        print(f'{username} said: {user_message} in {channel}')

        is_private = user_message.startswith('?')
        user_message = user_message[1:] if is_private else user_message

        await send_message(message, user_message, is_private)

    client.run(TOKEN)

run_discord_bot()

async def send_message(message, user_message, is_private):
    try:
        response = handle_response(user_message)
        await (message.author.send(response) if is_private else message.channel.send(response))
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

responses.py :

```py
def handle_response(message) -> str:
  p_message = message.lower()

  if 'hello' in p_message:
      print("Debug: 'Hello' detected")
      return 'Hello there!'
  elif 'damn' in p_message:
      print("Debug: 'Damn' detected")
      return "God damn it"
  else:
      print("Debug: Unknown message")
      return "I'm not sure how to respond to that"
```

So I thought it has a problem in the bot.py with the on_message function but that wasn't the problem and it didn't help

Comment: You did not provide enough information to understand your problem. Are you getting an error message?